# checking for ANY NULL object before ToLower

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception, any

I have an object where a property may exist or may not exist.

```
if(response.AddressInformation.AddressResponses.Any(inf => inf.AddressResponse.matchCodeStatus.ToLower().Equals("usps_match")))
{

}
```

I have two array items of `AddressResponse`. First item has null for `matchCodeStatus` and thats where I get `object not set to an instance` exception. How can I achieve my target and escape this exception?

I tried to put a null check before my IF, but it didnt work

```
if(response.AddressInformation.AddressResponses.Any(inf => inf.AddressResponse.matchCodeStatus != null)
```

Comment: Your title explains how - check for `null` *before* you try to invoke instance methods like `ToLower()`.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp Check my edited post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What about `inf => inf.AddressResponse.matchCodeStatus != null && inf.AddressResponse.matchCodeStatus.ToLower().Equals("usps_match")`?

Comment: @stickybit oh my bad for not placing the null check at the proper place. It works

Answer (score 0):

As of C# 6, you can also use a null conditional operator `?.` :

```
inf => inf.AddressResponse.matchCodeStatus?.ToLower().Equals("usps_match"))
```